# Oracle SQL: Count a time period when the value was over the threshold

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My table MEASUREMENTS (Oracle SQL 12) has 3 columns: DT - measurement timestamp, MEASUREMENT - value, THRESHOLD - upper limit.

Sometimes measurements are above the threshold. Trying to calculate time periods when the measurement value was higher than the threshold.

```
DT             | MEASUREMENT | THRESHOLD          
---------------+-------------+--------------------
04.08.16 01:10 | 60,5        | 70,0               
04.08.16 01:20 | 65,5        | 70,0               
04.08.16 01:30 | 68,1        | 70,0               
04.08.16 01:40 | 70,1*       | 70,0 //period start
04.08.16 01:50 | 70,1*       | 70,0               
04.08.16 02:00 | 70,75*      | 70,0 //period end  
04.08.16 02:10 | 53,5        | 70,0               
04.08.16 02:20 | 50,15       | 70,0               
04.08.16 02:30 | 52,15       | 70,0               
04.08.16 02:40 | 53,15       | 70,0
```

Expected result (02:00-01:40=00:20):

```
DURATION | START          | END
---------+----------------+---------------
00:20    | 04.08.16 01:40 | 04.08.16 02:00
```

Comment: what is the data type of DT column ?

Comment: Privet. Why your period end is 02:00 and not 01:50? Is there a rule?

Comment: DT type is DATETIME. Period ends at 02:00 as the measurement from the sensor at 02:00 was higher than the threshold (70,75>70,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use two row_numbers, you can directly use it via cumulative approach :

```
select max(dt) - min(dt) as duration, min(dt), max(dt)
from (select *, row_number() over (order by dt) as seq,
                sum(case when measurement > threshold then 1 else 0 end) over(order by dt) as grp
      from table
     ) t
where measurement > threshold
group by (seq - grp);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what advantage there is to a cumulative sum versus two row numbers, but this is also likely to be a valid approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()` to identify the periods.  This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The following returns each period where the measurement exceeds the threshold:

```
select max(dt) - min(dt) as duration, min(dt), max(dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when measurement > threshold then 1 else 2 end), order by dt) as seqnum_t
      from t
     ) t
where measurement > threshold
group by (seqnum - seqnum_t)
```

Comment: Thank you, likely there's a way to deal with it without a procedure

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm) clause (plus some extra info):

```
WITH t (DT, MEASUREMENT, THRESHOLD) AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('01:10', 'hh24:mi'), 60.5  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('01:20', 'hh24:mi'), 65.5  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('01:30', 'hh24:mi'), 68.1  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('01:40', 'hh24:mi'), 70.1  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('01:50', 'hh24:mi'), 70.1  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('02:00', 'hh24:mi'), 70.75 , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('02:10', 'hh24:mi'), 53.5  , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('02:20', 'hh24:mi'), 50.15 , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('02:30', 'hh24:mi'), 52.15 , 70 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_DATE('02:40', 'hh24:mi'), 53.15 , 70 FROM dual)
SELECT MEASUREMENT_MAX, match_num, FIRST_DT, LAST_DT, (LAST_DT-FIRST_DT)*24*60 AS DURATION
FROM t
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        ORDER BY DT
        MEASURES 
            FINAL MAX(MEASUREMENT) AS MEASUREMENT_MAX,
            MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_num,
            FINAL LAST(DT) AS LAST_DT,
            FINAL FIRST(DT) AS FIRST_DT
        PATTERN (a+)
        DEFINE
            a AS MEASUREMENT > THRESHOLD);


MEASUREMENT_MAX    match_num   FIRST_DT              LAST_DT                DURATION
70.75              3           01.06.2018 01:40:00   01.06.2018 02:00:00    20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using row_number analytical function:

```
SQL> WITH measurements (DT, MEASUREMENT, THRESHOLD) AS (
  2      select to_date('04.08.16 01:10', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 60.5, 70.0 from dual union all
  3      select to_date('04.08.16 01:20', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 65.5, 70.0 from dual union all
  4      select to_date('04.08.16 01:30', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 68.1, 70.0 from dual union all
  5      select to_date('04.08.16 01:40', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 70.1, 70.0 from dual union all
  6      select to_date('04.08.16 01:50', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 70.1, 70.0 from dual union all
  7      select to_date('04.08.16 02:00', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 70.75, 70.0 from dual union all
  8      select to_date('04.08.16 02:10', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 53.5, 70.0 from dual union all
  9      select to_date('04.08.16 02:20', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 50.15, 70.0 from dual union all
 10      select to_date('04.08.16 02:30', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 52.15, 70.0 from dual union all
 11      select to_date('04.08.16 02:40', 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI'), 53.15, 70.0 from dual),
 12  ---------------------
 13  ---- end of data preparation
 14  ---------------------
 15  calculated_values AS (
 16    SELECT DT,
 17           MEASUREMENT,
 18           THRESHOLD,
 19           row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN MEASUREMENT > THRESHOLD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY dt) rn,
 20           CASE WHEN MEASUREMENT > THRESHOLD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END threshold_flag
 21      FROM measurements)
 22  SELECT cast(numtodsinterval(MAX(dt)-MIN(dt), 'DAY') AS INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)) AS duration,
 23         MIN(dt) AS "START",
 24         MAX(dt) AS  "END"
 25    FROM calculated_values
 26   WHERE threshold_flag > 0
 27   GROUP BY rn;
```

OUTPUT:

```
DURATION    START                END
----------- -------------------- --------------------
+0 00:20:00 8/4/2016 1:40:00     8/4/2016 2:00:00
```

Your query will be:

```
WITH calculated_values AS ( 
  SELECT DT, 
         MEASUREMENT, 
         THRESHOLD, 
         row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt) - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN MEASUREMENT > THRESHOLD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY dt) rn,
         CASE WHEN MEASUREMENT > THRESHOLD THEN 1 ELSE 0 END threshold_flag
    FROM measurements)
SELECT cast(numtodsinterval(MAX(dt)-MIN(dt), 'DAY') AS INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)) AS duration, 
       MIN(dt) AS "START", 
       MAX(dt) AS  "END"
  FROM calculated_values
 WHERE threshold_flag > 0
 GROUP BY rn;
```